# Why HashSets with same elements return different values when calling to GetHashCode()?

Tags: c#, .net, set, hashcode

Why `HashSet<T>.GetHashCode()` returns different hashcodes when they have the same elements?

For instance:

```
[Fact]
public void EqualSetsHaveSameHashCodes()
{
    var set1 = new HashSet<int>(new [] { 1, 2, 3 } );
    var set2 = new HashSet<int>(new [] { 1, 2, 3 } );

    Assert.Equal(set1.GetHashCode(), set2.GetHashCode());
}
```

This test fails. Why?

How can I get the result I need? **"Equal sets give the same hashcode"**

Comment: You would have to implement your own GetHashCode function that is based on the elements.

Comment: Check out the docs for Hashset.GetHashCode method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#methods

Comment: You hash is comparing two arrays, not the contents of the arrays.

Comment: Equal sets **do** give the same hashcode. Your `set1` and `set2` are not equal because they are different objects. Test it; `set1.Equals(set2)` returns `false`.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why do you care about the `HashCode`? What is your **real underlying** problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashSet<T>` by default does not have value equality semantics. It has reference equality semantics, so two distinct hash sets won't be equal or have the same hash code even if the containing elements are the same.

You need to use a special purpose `IEqualityComparer<HashSet<int>>` to get the behavior you want. You can roll your own or use the default one the framework provides for you:

```
var hashSetOfIntComparer = HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer();

//will evaluate to true
var haveSameHash = hashSetOfIntComparer.GetHashCode(set1) ==
                   hashSetOfIntComparer.GetHashCode(set2);
```

So, to make a long story short:

> How can I get the result I need? **"Equal sets give the same hashcode"**

You can't if you are planning on using the default implementation of `HashSet<T>.GetHashCode()`. You either use a special purpose comparer or you extend `HashSet<T>` and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to suit your needs.

Comment: Do you know why isn't there a static method in `HashSet<T>` and if it is safe to have a static comparer, e.g. `private static readonly IEqualityComparer<MyClass> myComparer = HashSet<MyClass>.CreateSetComparer()` and use it everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

By default (and unless otherwise specifically documented), reference types are only considered equal if they reference the same object. As a developer, you can override the Equals() and GetHashCode() methods so that objects that you consider equal return true for the Equals and the same int for GetHashCode.

Depending on which test framework you are using, there will be either CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent() or an override to Assert.Equal that takes a comparer.

Comment: If you want compare sets, and not hash code, you have already built-in method for it (`SetEquals`), not need to go with extra library.

Answer (score -3):

You could implement a custom HashSet that overrides the GetHashCode function which generates a new hashcode from all of the contents like below:

```
public class HashSetWithGetHashCode<T> : HashSet<T>
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;
            foreach (var item in this)
                hash = hash * 23 + item.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would give you a O(n) complexity, that is not desirable to get a hash code. I'm afraid that's the reason of the downvote.

Comment: I don't see any way of getting faster than O(N), but more worryingly this implementation depends on the ordering, which isn't appropriate for a HashSet.

Comment: Good catch Jon Skeet. Barring the previously mentioned performance issues, would it be acceptable to either sort the elements in this function, or keep a parallel collection of sorted items in which the hash would be operated on?

Comment: This is completely wrong. Equal sets have to produce the same hash code, and iterating over `HashSet` or `Dictionary` elements does not have the guarantee on the order. Using the same weight though for all elements would do the trick.